# Android: how to switch with timer?

Tags: android, timer, android-widget, switch-statement, timertask

I am trying to activate a sound with an switch widget, so I can turn it off as well. Though I also want it to shut down automatically of after a few seconds. everything works though the app crashes on  `s.performClick();`
anyone know how to fix the problem I have?

down here is my full code of the fragment.

```
public static class Therapy extends Fragment implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
    MediaPlayer player = null;
    Switch s;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.therapy, container, false);           
        Switch s = (Switch)v.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return v;   
    }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            s.performClick();
        }

    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {                    
                player = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.bird1);
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.start();

                MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
                Timer myTimer = new Timer();
                myTimer.schedule(myTask, 1000);
            } else {
                player.stop();
                player.release();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does the logcat say when the app crashes?

Comment: [link picture](http://oi48.tinypic.com/2my1z5u.jpg)

that, is the error i get from logcat, now trying it with an Handler and Hanler.postDelayd, still crashes on s.performClick();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a guess here, since I didn't attempt to build your code and run it, but:

`s.performClick()` is a UI-accessing operation, and cannot be done with a `Timer`.  You might want to consider having the `Timer` call [`Handler.post`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) (passing in a Runnable) to make sure your UI-accessing stuff doesn't make Android complain.  Alternately, depending on your needs, you could just build a timer entirely with `Handler.postDelayed`.

Comment: i took your suggestion of using handlers, and in this case it defiantly is more logical to use. i now got this within my "onCheckedChange listener" 'mHandler.removeCallbacks(r); mHandler.postDelayed(r, 5000);' and this within my fragment: '  Runnable r=new Runnable() { public void run() { s.performClick(); } };' it still crashes tho. any idea?

Comment: I just found out my switch objective was also declared in the wrong spot, it works now, thanks allot Alex!